# Calculate flux of vector field

Tags: analysis, riemannian-geometry, polar-coordinates, vector-fields

I want to calculate the flux of the vector field $$X(x,y)=y\partial_x-x\partial_y$$
in $\mathbb R^2$ written in polar coordinates ($\partial_x:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and so on).

**Step 1:** transform X to polar coordinates

It is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi=atan2(y,x)$, so that we get:
$$\partial_x=\partial_r \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\partial_\phi \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=cos\phi \partial_r - \frac{1}{r}sin\phi \partial_\phi$$
and $$\partial_y=\partial_r \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\partial_\phi \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=sin\phi\partial_r+\frac{1}{r}cos\phi\partial_\phi.$$
So using $x=rcos\phi$ and $y=rsin\phi$ and knowing $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$  we can deduce that
$$X(r,\phi)=-\partial_\phi.$$

**Step 2:** calculate the flux

This is the point where I dont know how to continue. I know that I have to find an integral curve by solving differential equations.

Comment: Doesn't the definition of flux require the choice of a surface, possibly with a boundary?

Comment: Our definition is: "The flux of a vector field $X$ is the function $\Phi:(p,t)\mapsto \gamma_p(t), \Phi: M \times \mathbb R \to M$." $\gamma_p(t)$ is the maximal integral curve $\gamma_p: I \to M$ with $\gamma_p(0)=p$, $M$ is a manifold, $X$ a vector vield on $M$. So in this case $M=\mathbb R^2$ I think.

Comment: Hint: at every point the vector is perpendicular to the radius from the origin to the point.

Comment: So the integral curves are circles? So $\gamma_p$ is the circle with center=origin, radius=norm($p$) and starting in $p$?

Comment: Yep that's it. You would also need to compute the velocity, which in this case is best expressed as a function of the radius.